# How to print inputs in new line

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey is there a way to print inputs like this:

Input:

```
Enter the minimum number of feet (not less than 0):
5
Enter the maximum number of feet (not more than 99):
10
```

How can one do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just do it like this:

```
print("Enter the minimum number of feet (not less than 0):")
minN = input()
print("Enter the maximum number of feet (not more than 99):")
maxN = input()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a new line to the input prompt with `\n` (Python newline character) like this:

```py
minFeet = input("Enter the minimum number of feet (not less than 0): \n")
maxFeet = input("Enter the maximum number of feet (not more than 99): \n")
```